# Visual Studio 15: remove double CTRL+S as a short cut of save file as

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Not only me but many developers are in the habit of pressing `ctrl+s` many times to save the file. Here comes the visual studio 15 that open a dialogue to `save file as` if you press the control+s more then ones.

How to remove the shortcut from the `vs 15`?

I checked and found that `ctrl+s, ctrl+s` is assigned to none as shown in screen shot given below:
[image]

**EDIT**

I am using a trial version
[image]

I have following extensions installed
[image]

[image]

The issue was automatically resolved after taking the latest updates of Visual Studio.

I apologise for not updating the question.

Comment: why don't just change yourself? Press save only once

Comment: why don't you just answer relevant? :P or  is it not possible to remove the shortcut?

Comment: I can't emulate in 15 Preview 2 double `Ctrl + S`. It does nothing.

Comment: I am using visual studio 15 professional and double `ctrls+s` is opening the `save file as`

Comment: You might improve the tags on the post - it is unclear whether you refer to visual studio 2015 or visual studio 15,  I use VS2015 professional, and single or double ctrls+s does only save. VS15 is only in Preview (beta). VS2015 has bug reporting under Help / Send feedback, so maybe also VS15. You might consider moving to the stable version of VS2015 rather than VS15. And which is your Preview version?

Comment: @harrymc Those are very good suggestions for the OP. Nevertheless, I have VS2015 (Community) and I also frequently experience this odd behaviour. After you said it didn't happen to you, I double checked and indeed it is not easy to reproduce by simply pressing Ctrl+S twice. I have the (bad) habit of issuing many Ctrl+S strokes as I code, so it happens frequently when I issue multiple strokes. Perhaps it will be easier for you to reproduce this by keeping Ctrl+S pressed?

Comment: @LuizVieira: It's difficult when post and bounty do not fully agree. With me, keeping Ctrl+S pressed also does not cause any problem. Maybe it's some extension : try [devenv.exe /SafeMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278.aspx).

Comment: @harrymc I just did as you suggested and the issue no longer happpens. So it might indeed be some extension. :/ Thank you for your help.

Comment: @harrymc I tracked it down and (in my case) the culprit seems to be the [Visual Studio 2015 Tools for Unity](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8d26236e-4a64-4d64-8486-7df95156aba9). It only happens with projects integrated with Unity. C++ or C# projects that have nothing to do with Unity do not show that odd "save as" behaviour.

Comment: @VikasBansal: Using a Preview/trial version means there will be bugs.

Answer (score 2):

Summary :

As this didn't happen on my version of Visual Studio Pro 2015,
I suggested running [devenv.exe /SafeMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278.aspx) to check for a rogue extension.

This was indeed the case, tracked by @LuizVieira to the extension
[Visual Studio 2015 Tools for Unity](http://Visual%20Studio%202015%20Tools%20for%20Unity.).

This extension has some issues with saving.
For example : [Why does Ctrl-S not always save?](https://www.reddit.com/r/VisualStudio2015/comments/41bjbt/why_does_ctrls_not_always_save/).
Here the workaround was :

> Going to Visual Studio > Tools > Options> Tools For Unity> General and
>   setting all options from explorer to true

Some other suggestions :

1. The problem can be a conflict with another extension - 
   see if it arrives when only this extension is enabled.
2. Try to map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to "Save All" as a
   workaround.

Comment: In `Tools>>Options`, I don't find any option `Tools For Unity`. I have updated and mention the version of Visual studio I am using. As Tools for Unity is not present in my VS then It must not be the reason of the conflict. Also, the issue was resolved when I had taken the updates.

Comment: @VikasBansal: Using a Preview/trial version means there will be bugs.